# how to sort array value inside an array with in a column using snowflake?

Tags: sql, arrays, database, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, backend

I have a demo code that creates a table and inserts a value in the table. I want to create a value in an array but the value inside an array needs to be in alphabetical order/sorting string. So, the 3rd and 4th rows tend to be equal.

```html
-- create a table
create table array_test (
    test_date date
    ,article_name varchar(20)
    ,description varchar(20)
)

-- insert the value
insert into array_test(test_date, article_name, description)
values ('2022-01-01', 'AAA', 'A')
insert into array_test(test_date, article_name, description)
values ('2022-01-02', 'AAA', 'A,B')
insert into array_test(test_date, article_name, description)
values ('2022-01-03', 'AAA', 'C,A,B')
insert into array_test(test_date, article_name, description)
values ('2022-01-03', 'AAA', 'B,C,A')
```

The expected result is

[image]

The array column is in curly braces but I need to have it in square brackets. How can that be done?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a JavaScript UDF to sort an array:

```
create or replace function u.udf.ARRAY_SORT(ARR array)
returns array
language javascript strict immutable
as
$$
    return ARR.sort();
$$;

select array_sort(['B','C','A']); -- Returns an array
```

| ARRAY_SORT(['B','C','A']) |
| --- |
| [ "A", "B", "C" ] |

However, the format your sample shows is a string not an array. If you want a string like that you can use a modified UDF:

```
create or replace function ARRAY_SORT_STRING(ARR array)
returns string
language javascript strict immutable
as
$$
    return ARR.sort().join();
$$;

select array_sort_string(['B','C','A']);  -- Returns a string
```

| ARRAY_SORT_STRING(['B','C','A']) |
| --- |
| A,B,C |